# GetComputerName() in Windows 7 on a Mac using VMWare Fails

Tags: windows, vmware

Windows 7 on a Mac with VMWare. GetComputerName is returning ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW (111) but a valid length of 16 and an empty name. Any ideas why it would be failing? It works correctly with other Windows emulations.

Here is the code for a console app that demonstrates the failure:

```
// GetComputerName.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.  
//  

#include "stdafx.h"  

#ifdef _DEBUG  
#define new DEBUG_NEW  
#endif  

#include <string>   // for string  
#include <vector>   // for vector  

using std::vector;  
using std::string;   

#ifdef _UNICODE  
using std::wstring;   
#define string wstring    
using std::wostringstream;  
#define ostringstream wostringstream  
#else  
#endif  

typedef vector<TCHAR> VTChar; // vtc  

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object  
using namespace std;  

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])  
{  
  TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
  DWORD dwComputerNameLength(MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH);  
  if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
  {  
    string strErrorFormat(_T("GetComputerName failed with %d; returned length was %d."));  
    VTChar vtcError(strErrorFormat.size() + 20, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strErrorFormat.c_str(), ::GetLastError(), dwComputerNameLength);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
  }    
  else  
  {  
    string strFormat(_T("GetComputerName returned \"%s\""));  
    VTChar vtcError(strFormat.size() + 30, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strFormat.c_str(), tcLocalComputerName);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
  }  

  return 0;  
}
```

A colleague worked with it awhile and found that if we made a second call, it would work. The app that was working actually did that in a roundabout way.

Here is the code for a console app that actually works:

```
// GetComputerName.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.  
//  

#include "stdafx.h"  

#ifdef _DEBUG  
#define new DEBUG_NEW  
#endif  

#include <string>   // for string  
#include <vector>   // for vector  

using std::vector;  
using std::string;   

#ifdef _UNICODE  
using std::wstring;   
#define string wstring    
using std::wostringstream;  
#define ostringstream wostringstream  
#else  
#endif  

typedef vector<TCHAR> VTChar; // vtc  

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object  
using namespace std;  

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])  
{  
  bool gotName(false);  
  TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
  DWORD dwComputerNameLength(MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH);  
  if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
  {  
    AfxMessageBox(_T("First GetComputerName failed."));  
    if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
    {  
      string strErrorFormat(_T("GetComputerName failed with %d; returned length was %d."));  
      VTChar vtcError(strErrorFormat.size() + 20, 0);  
      _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strErrorFormat.c_str(), ::GetLastError(), dwComputerNameLength);  
      AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
    }  
    else  
      gotName= true;
  }    
  else
    gotName= true;  

  if(gotName)    
  {  
    string strFormat(_T("GetComputerName returned \"%s\""));  
    VTChar vtcError(strFormat.size() + 30, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strFormat.c_str(), tcLocalComputerName);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
  }  

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: Code please, including the declaration of variable used

Comment: Extremely unlikely that this has anything to do with VMware. Show your code.

Comment: I will post as soon as I can. I agree it is likely not VMWare, but the code is solid. It works on Windows of all flavors (I wrote it years ago), on PCs and Macs running VMs. However, the same code in a different app works on the same machine. My suspicion is it has to do with the app type. FWIW, GetEnvironmentVariable for "COMPUTERNAME" succeeds, but returns an empty name. I have an idea of what to test.

Comment: What exactly is the computer's name?

Comment: The actual name is "WIN-N6LLD42BT79"

Answer (score 3):

When debugging Windows API calls, you must call `::GetLastError()` **immediately** after the failed call.

Not this:

```
if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
{  
    string strErrorFormat(_T("GetComputerName failed with %d; returned length was %d."));  
    VTChar vtcError(strErrorFormat.size() + 20, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strErrorFormat.c_str(), ::GetLastError(), dwComputerNameLength);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
}
```

But this:

```
if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
{
    DWORD apiError = ::GetLastError();
    string strErrorFormat(_T("GetComputerName failed with %d; returned length was %d."));  
    VTChar vtcError(strErrorFormat.size() + 20, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strErrorFormat.c_str(), apiError, dwComputerNameLength);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
}
```

Something as simple as declaring a string variable, as your example does, can overwrite the thread last-error value.  How?  Well, `std::string` dynamically allocates a buffer to hold the content.  That dynamic allocation requires a call to an allocator, which may have enough space in its internal heap, or may need to grow the heap.  If it needs to grow the heap, an OS call will be used to do so, and now you're looking at the last-error value from `::VirtualAlloc` instead of `::GetComputerName`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to make the call a second time.

Here is the code for a console app that actually works:

```
// GetComputerName.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.  
//  

#include "stdafx.h"  

#ifdef _DEBUG  
#define new DEBUG_NEW  
#endif  

#include <string>   // for string  
#include <vector>   // for vector  

using std::vector;  
using std::string;   

#ifdef _UNICODE  
using std::wstring;   
#define string wstring    
using std::wostringstream;  
#define ostringstream wostringstream  
#else  
#endif  

typedef vector<TCHAR> VTChar; // vtc  

CWinApp theApp;  // The one and only application object  
using namespace std;  

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])  
{  
  bool gotName(false);  
  TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
  DWORD dwComputerNameLength(_countof(tcLocalComputerName));  
  if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
  {  
    dwComputerNameLength= _countof(tcLocalComputerName);  
    AfxMessageBox(_T("First GetComputerName failed."));  
    if(!::GetComputerName(tcLocalComputerName, &dwComputerNameLength))  
    {  
      DWORD dwLastError(::GetLastError());  
      string strErrorFormat(_T("GetComputerName failed with %d; returned length was %d."));  
      VTChar vtcError(strErrorFormat.size() + 20, 0);  
      _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strErrorFormat.c_str(), dwLastError, dwComputerNameLength);  
      AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
    }  
    else  
      gotName= true;
  }    
  else
    gotName= true;  

  if(gotName)    
  {  
    string strFormat(_T("GetComputerName returned \"%s\""));  
    VTChar vtcError(strFormat.size() + 30, 0);  
    _stprintf_s(&vtcError[0], vtcError.size(), strFormat.c_str(), tcLocalComputerName);  
    AfxMessageBox(&vtcError[0], MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);  
  }  

  return 0;  
}
```

Comment: This should be an edit to your original question, not a separate answer.

Comment: @GigaWatt: This is a low quality answer, it should include more detail like a code snippet and what values get returned on the first and second call.  But it is an answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I posted that comment before the edit.  Check the revision history.

Comment: @GigaWatt: It was better to have the "solution" code in the answer.  And the summary explanation.

Comment: BTW those macros are horrible.  Consider using `typedef std::wstring tstring;` or `typedef std::string tstring;` depending on UNICODE (and then remove `using std::string;`)

Comment: This is not the correct solution, and could potentially have resulted in a buffer overflow - you're taking the required buffer length (provided by the first call) and feeding it to the second call as if it were the *actual* buffer length.  As it happens, the required buffer length is the actual buffer length, so it works, but that's just a lucky coincidence.

Comment: You are correct - I noted that in the working code and changed it. Forgot to come here and update.

Comment: The code as updated looks like it will work, but there's no need to call GetComputerName twice.  The extra call is harmless but redundant.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
DWORD dwComputerNameLength(MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH);
```

The [documentation for GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is clear:

> lpnSize [in, out]
>
> On input, specifies the size of the buffer, in TCHARs.

So the correct code is

```
TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
DWORD dwComputerNameLength(MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1);
```

or even better,

```
TCHAR tcLocalComputerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1]= {_T('\0')};  
DWORD dwComputerNameLength(_countof(tcLocalComputerName));
```

Comment: I will see if that makes a difference in this case.